# listar todos los usuarios yii2 en el form

Tags: yii2

Hola mi duda es la siguiente tengo esta vista[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al crear una asistencia se me despliega esta otra vista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahí puedo escoger la fecha y el nombre de solo un mecánico y abajo sale un checkbox para ver si asistió o no

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi pregunta es la siguiente se puede hacer que en vez de que tenga que escoger yo el nombre del mecánico se me despliegue instantáneamente todos los mecánicos y al lado de ellos el checkbox y así cuando guarde, se me guardara la fecha y si presiono "ver"  se desplegara todos los mecánicos con su respectiva asistencia

este es el código del form para buscar un mecanico

`<?= $form->field($model, 'mecanico_id')
        ->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Mecanico::find()->all(), 'id_mecanico', 'nombre'),['prompt'=>'Escoja el Mecánico'])
    ?>`

Answer (score 2):

hola buenas solo tienes que añadir un multiple para que puedas escoger varios a la vez, lo lógico sería que después tuvieras otra vista para cumplimentar que mecánico asistió y ahí si quieres pongas el checkbox de los que guardes o como en este caso con un arrayhelper y una consulta específica los cargues.

el código de arriba debería ser así;

```
$form->field($model, 'mecanico_id[]')            
         ->dropDownList(
           ArrayHelper::map(Mecanico::find()->all(), 'id_mecanico', 'nombre'),
         [
          'prompt'=>'Escoja al menos un mecánico'
          'multiple'=>'multiple'
          'class'=>'chosen-select input-md required',              
         ]             
        );
```